# jsp page to groovy Controller working in webcentersite

Tags: oracle12c, webcenter-sites

How to integrate the jsp page to groovy Controller in webcentersite(oracle) & page navigation

Comment: This [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vYgNN77sT14) makes a Page via MVC pattern and another [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ulZ9kmY3t38) directly by adding attributes to page. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In WCS12c,when you create the template(JSP page) you have to associate respective controller into it.Because when you render the template it will first check whether it has controller or not if controller present then template would call controllor first and  do operation ,fetch data and store in map object.

for ex:do opertaion and set into map object models.put("set map object",getmapvalue)

After controller executed it will come to template and execute such as if we are get those map object which setting in controller you would see the respective JSON format.With help of that json you can retrieve the data as per our need.

For calling the controller object you can simply use this way:

${get map object}